# Remove review probe which belongs on workplace.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug

The review probe

[image]

causes the reviewer (at least me) to add a comment that this belongs on workplace.stackexchange.com. If one wants to be helpful and search for eventual duplicates already, it's an unnecessary effort. It's not a big deal because adding a comment doesn't make you fail the review, but it's the unneeded effort which is unmotivating.

Comment: link to review task: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16406178

Comment: Closing it would be the right action and leaving a comment never fails an audit. Why should it be removed, except that you did unneeded effort?

Comment: @rene There's no other reason than the unneeded effort. It's not a big deal and I made this more clear in the question.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I'm not sure though if or how mods can remove this from being used as an audit.

Comment: Unneeded effort doesn't sound like a valid reason for removing a question from the audit pool. Every audit causes unneeded effort, because these questions have been dealt with long time ago.

Comment: Then I'd call this unneeded unneeded effort...

Comment: speaking of Workplace, per my reading of [their Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) this question is off-topic over there, so the comment you wanted to ask looks misleading

Comment: This is just plain off topic.  Good audit IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with the audit - the question is clearly off-topic in its current state and should be voted as such ("too broad" or "unclear" are valid close reasons for that post).

It is up to you to provide comments, but in this particular case I don't think question will be on-topic on any SE site including [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Indeed effort spend looking/acting on audit questions is wasted. It is price we have to pay to protect site from completely mindless reviewers. If you have better proposal - ask new question...